# Ubuntu 22.04 HP laptop Irisxe graphics no HDMI signal

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, hdmi, i915

After searching for quite a few days and trying different solutions I still cannot resolve this issue, thus, I'm asking for help.

I have a new HP laptop (HP HP Laptop 17t-cn200) with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS installed (Linux 6.1.0-1026-oem
kernel) along with Windows 11 as dual boot.  Windows detects the HDMI port just fine and I can plug in my external monitor but Ubuntu does not recognize it. This is the list of things I tried so far:

- Boot to Windows (external monitor detected and works fine)
- Change HDMI cable (3 separate cables worked on Windows)
- Disable secure boot (enabled or disable external monitor not detected)
- Tried 2 other different Debian-based distros (MX-23.1_x64 “ahs” with 6.4 kernel) and Debian 12:  debian-live-12.2.0-amd64-cinnamon.iso ran xrandr on both and got no HDMI info (it wasn't marked as detected, it didn't show up).
- Followed the Intel guide for installing drivers: https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/installation-guides/ubuntu/ubuntu-jammy-arc.html All drivers were installed correctly for Linux 6.1.0-1026-oem kernel. I needed to downgrade to this kernel because there seems to be an issue with intel-i915-kdms on kernels 6.2 and up: https://community.intel.com/t5/Graphics/Ubuntu-intel-i915-kdms-error-on-update/td-p/1524576 I tried followed that bug report but I wasn't able to find the chat that was opened at the end of that conversation.
- Installed Oibaf graphic drivers, installation went fine, no errors but still no HDMI on xrandr.

I'm aware that this particular laptop doesn't provide USB ports with video capacity (it only has USB 3.0 data ports) which is why I'm currently using a USB to HDMI device for connecting my external monitor (which works fine after installing their drivers).

Here is the result of a few commands and also a probe I did a few days ago: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=26c356c486

xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3520 x 1200, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected 1600x900+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
   1600x900      60.07*+  60.07    40.05  
   1400x900      60.07  
   1440x810      60.07  
   1368x768      60.07  
   1280x800      60.07  
   1280x720      60.07  
   1024x768      60.07  
   960x720       60.07  
   928x696       60.07  
   896x672       60.07  
   1024x576      60.07  
   960x600       60.07  
   960x540       60.07  
   800x600       60.07  
   840x525       60.07  
   864x486       60.07  
   700x525       60.07  
   800x450       60.07  
   640x512       60.07  
   700x450       60.07  
   640x480       60.07  
   720x405       60.07  
   684x384       60.07  
   640x360       60.07  
   512x384       60.07  
   512x288       60.07  
   480x270       60.07  
   400x300       60.07  
   432x243       60.07  
   320x240       60.07  
   360x202       60.06  
   320x180       60.07  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-4-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1-1 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024     59.89 +
   1920x1200     59.88* 
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1366x768      59.88  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x480       59.94
```

It detects the laptop default screen as well as my USB to HDMI device but it doesn't provide an HDMI option.

inxi -Gxxxz:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915 v: backported to
    6.1.0-1026 from (b434e44e14397) using backports I915_23.8.20_PSB_230810.22
    ports: active: eDP-1 empty: DP-1, DP-2, DP-3, DP-4 bus-ID: 00:02.0
    chip-ID: 8086:46a8 class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: Luxvisions Innotech HP TrueVision HD Camera type: USB
    driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 1-1:2 chip-ID: 30c9:0064 class-ID: fe01
    serial: <filter>
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 compositor: gnome-shell v: 42.9
    driver: X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: evdi,i915
    display-ID: :0.0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 3520x1200 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 931x318mm (36.7x12.5")
    s-diag: 984mm (38.7")
  Monitor-1: DVI-I-1-1 mapped: DVI-I-1 pos: primary,left model: No Monitor
    serial: <filter> res: 1920x1200 hz: 60 size: N/A modes: max: 1280x1024
    min: 640x480
  Monitor-2: eDP-1 pos: right model: AU Optronics res: 1600x900 hz: 60
    dpi: 106 size: 382x215mm (15.0x8.5") diag: 438mm (17.3") modes: 1600x900
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa
    24.0~git2312080600.d17ddc~oibaf~j (git-d17ddcc 2023-12-08 jammy-oibaf-ppa)
    compat-v: 4.6 direct render: Yes
```

lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 46a8 (rev 0c)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 899b
```

I've seen in other posts that the correct name for the driver appears for them but for me it always show as "Intel Corporation Device 46a8 (rev 0c)"

lsmod | grep i915:

```
i915                 3948544  30
intel_vsec             20480  1 i915
compat                 20480  6 intel_vsec,mei_hdcp,mei,mei_pxp,mei_me,i915
drm_display_helper    188416  2 compat,i915
cec                    81920  2 drm_display_helper,i915
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        208896  3 drm_display_helper,evdi,i915
drm                   598016  20 drm_kms_helper,drm_display_helper,evdi,i915
video                  65536  1 i915
```

Following this intel's page: https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/devices/hardware-table.html running: lspci -nn |grep  -Ei 'VGA|DISPLAY' yields:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:46a8] (rev 0c)
```

This means my device: 46a8 fits into the `Intel® UHD Graphics Xe Alder Lake` category.

I don't know what else to do at this point, I've seen similar issues with other Distros but their solutions seem to be targeted to their distros. I also saw some posts saying the HDMI port was mapped to a DVI or DP one but I'm not sure if that is the case here.

Sorry for the long post and if there is any other info I might provide, I'll be happy to. Thanks!